# create and use screen like android 4.0.4 call screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to reuse android 4.0.4 call screen. but I cant access some widget classes which they are using. Can any one suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The source to Android is available; nothing prevents you from downloading it, getting the source to the widget you're interested in, and including that source (and any resources it needs) in your project. People have been doing this since Android was introduced.

Comment: Thanks For comment mah. But I tried to find and couldn'd succeed in finding the layout which appears when there is incoming call (i.e receive or reject call)

Comment: Did you try looking in the phone application? This is within the application itself, not within the operating system. It appears to be in the source tree at packages/apps/Phone.

Comment: Thanks much for reply mah. The do using object of com.android.internal.widget.multiwaveview.MultiWaveView.java class for animation. But I cant import this class in my project because this class is hidden

Comment: If you locate the source of MultiWaveView.java in your downloaded Android source tree, you can pull it (and anything it needs) into your project; you may need to change its package so that it can coexist with your system. Since you're able to do that, you can also make your copy of it not be hidden.